# Error when trying to iterate through a hashmap in java with a for each loop

Tags: java, hashmap

when i try to run this code

```
void wordsContainingLetter(char c){
        for(String s:wordbank.keySet()){
            char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
            boolean contains=false;
            for (char ch:chars) {
                if(ch==c){
                    contains=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!contains){
                wordbank.remove(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

it gives me this error on the for each loop`Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`
this is the definition of the hashmap `HashMap<String,Integer> wordbank = new HashMap<String,Integer>();`
it is not blank when the code is run

im expecting the for each loop to iterate through the hashmap

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. Because I was looping through it and trying to remove something from it simultaneously, it caused a conflict. so instead I will create a new hashmap that contains the one I want to remove and then go through the new one and remove the ones from the main wordbank

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you figured it out, but since you are using a `HashMap`, there is a much easier way to do it using the built-in `removeAll` method.

Try this

```java
void wordsContainingLetter(char c){
  wordbank.keySet().removeAll(wordbank.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().contains(String.valueOf(c))).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(
        Collectors.toList()));
}
```